# Mysterious black hands on chapter 383 of Hunter x Hunter

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

On *Hunter x Hunter* chapter 383, something that looks like black hands suddenly appear and it took 1 princess life.

> [image: the black hand thingy]

Is that a "Nen" or is it the Black Continent thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the succeeding pages of that chapter, Fugetsu Hui Guo Rou clearly realizes what it was and said to herself that:

> Leaving the ship...doesn't mean escape...but death?!

Also, after saving Kacho Hui Guo Rou, or her Nen beast to be exact, she told her that:

> There's punishment for leaving the ship.

This leads to the conclusion that it is probably a Nen ability or something similar, *put in place around the ship to detect and prevent people leaving and eliminate them if they ever make it out*. As to who put this up, it was never revealed if I recall correctly.

Comment: It cannot be something from the dark continent as they haven't even reached that yet. I wouldn't want to spoil other things but I suggest you back read a few volumes behind since you missed some important details that are too long to explain, especially about this expedition they are currently in. If you find it hard to follow the manga from where the anime left off, I suggest you read it over at the start. I haven't yet watched the anime so I'm not sure which details they left off or something.